# How to vectorize a function with default parameter values?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

With `numba`, it is usually no problem to compile a function that takes extra arguments with default values (and this question has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123657/numba-calling-jit-with-explicit-signature-using-arguments-with-default-values)), e.g.:

```
@numba.jit
def f(a, b=1):
    return a + b
```

I am trying to achieve the same feature *not* with `jit` but with **`vectorize`** instead. That is, the `Omitted` keyword proposed in the related question does not work here anymore:

```
@numba.vectorize
def f(a, b=1):
    return a + b

a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
f(a) # Raises ValueError: invalid number of arguments
f(a, 2) # Works OK

@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)', 'float64(float64, Omitted(float64))'])
def f(a, b=1):
    return a + b # Raises NotImplementedError
```

Is there a clean way around this problem? e.g. by providing `vectorize` with a specific signature maybe?

Comment: `@vectorize; lambda x: f(x)`? But that seems just wrong.

Comment: Did you try with `guvectorize`? https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numba: calling jit with explicit signature using arguments with default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123657/numba-calling-jit-with-explicit-signature-using-arguments-with-default-values)

Comment: @MadPhysicist it seems to run OK, but it becomes much slower, slower than numpy alone on this simple example :(

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Isn't `guvectorize` for functions that applies to subsets of an array instead of its individual elements? I have a hard time seeing how to use `guvectorize` so that it mimics the behavior of `vectorize`... Or maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: @Aratz I thought two signatures could be passed in the second argument string but it doesn't seem to be the case.